# Issue @import angular_components material css in AngularDart

Tags: sass, angular-material, angular-components, angular-dart

I am having an issue importing the anugular_components material.scss package.  For some reason Sass is not able to locate the scss files in the angular_components package.

The error is:

```
/* Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
 *   ,
 * 1 | @import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';
 *   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 *   '
 *   wakeup_component.scss 1:9  root stylesheet */
```

My pubspec.yaml file looks like this:

```
name: ct
description: A web app for CasaTunes using Angular Dart and Material Design
# version: 1.0.0
# homepage: https://www.casatunes.com

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^6.0.0-alpha+1
  angular_components: ^0.14.0-alpha+1
  angular_router: ^2.0.0-alpha+24

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.3.0
  build_runner: ^1.6.0
  build_test: ^0.10.8
  build_web_compilers: ^2.3.0
  pedantic: ^1.8.0
  test: ^1.6.0
  sass_builder: ^2.1.2
  casatunes_rest:
    path: /Users/davidkrinker/Development/CasaTunes REST API/dart/api
```

I am using Sass version: 1.26.5
Using WebStorm

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to disable WebStorm's file watching to automatically build the .css files from the .scss files.